# How can I change this button background color of the specific button that i have clicked? using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, simple-html-dom

I want to change the button's background color of the specific button that I have clicked, do I need to use loops and also condition? I tried to access the first index but I don't know how can I change the other button's background color.

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

let arraySelected = [];

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', seatFunction);
});


function seatFunction(e) {

  const {
    value
  } = e.target;
  let newArray = arraySelected;
  const index = arraySelected.findIndex((element) => element === value);

  let findValue = arraySelected.find((element) => element == value);

  if (index !== -1) {
    console.log(`The ${value} has been removed into the array.`);
    // console.log(`The ${index} is the '${value}' of the item that has been removed.`);    
    newArray.splice(index, 1);
    console.log(newArray);
    buttons[0].style.backgroundColor = null;

  } else {
    console.log(`${value} has been pushed into the array.`)
    arraySelected.push(value);
    console.log(arraySelected);
    buttons[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";

  }

  // Checking if the array is empty.
  if (arraySelected.length === 0) {
    alert(`The last value '${value}' has been removed\r\nThe array now is empty!`);

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="btn seat" value="A">A</button>
  <button class="btn seat" value="B">B</button>
  <button class="btn seat" value="C">C</button>
  <button class="btn seat" value="D">D</button>
  <button class="btn seat" value="E">E</button>
  <button class="btn seat" value="F">F</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're approaching it the right way. You just need to loop over all the buttons and reset their background, and then change the background of the button you clicked on.

I'm using [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) and CSS for this example.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', seatFunction, false);
});

function seatFunction() {
  buttons.forEach(btn => btn.classList.remove('active'));
  this.classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
.active { background-color: Tomato; }
.btn:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="btn seat" value="A">A</button>
  <button class="btn seat" value="B">B</button>
  <button class="btn seat" value="C">C</button>
  <button class="btn seat" value="D">D</button>
  <button class="btn seat" value="E">E</button>
  <button class="btn seat" value="F">F</button>
</div>
```

Comment: do you have any idea how can I pass all data on that array into the database? or should I pass it into PHP first before inserting it into database?

Comment: You should ask a new question @HideOnBush so we can help debug code that you provide as [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Use loop to remove bgcolor from other buttons then add it to clicked button.

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

let arraySelected = [];

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    seatFunction(button)
  });
});

function seatFunction(a) {
  buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.style.background = "none";
  });

  a.style.background = "red";
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="btn seat" value="A">A</button>
  <button class="btn seat" value="B">B</button>
  <button class="btn seat" value="C">C</button>
  <button class="btn seat" value="D">D</button>
  <button class="btn seat" value="E">E</button>
  <button class="btn seat" value="F">F</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need all of that (loop and condition), and you do not need to create another array.

First, I advise you to work with CSS class in order to change any style, even dynamically:

```
.active {
    background-color: #00d4b1;
}
```

So now the logic is when a button is clicked "if there is the `active` class on it, remove the active class, else attach the `active` class."

```
function seatFunction(e){
    e.target.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

The beginning of your script is good:

```
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', seatFunction);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you install jquery, you can achieve this easily.

just put this in your html header and try

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
```

In your JS, put like this

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
   $('.btn').css({"background":""});
   $(this).css({"background":"red"}); //put the color you want
});
```

Comment: Why use an external and heavy library for something easily doable with vanilla Javascript? You will loose performance, and JQuery is not vey useful these days in comparison of 10 years ago.

Comment: Yes, I agree there are many ways to do this, jquery is only one of the way to do so, as long as the problem is able to solve, why not?

Comment: 1. Performance, using a whole external library is not worse for this kind of small thing (kill a buzz with a bazooka) 

2. Learn how to use vanilla javascript is more useful for your developer journey. For example if you want to learn a javascript framework, knowing Jquery is useless, but knowing javascript is useful.